# UIButton doesn't work after animation

Tags: iphone, ios

When the user taps on the button "Next", a other button should disappear and the Next button itself should be on the same place as it was, and a tableView should appear. This happens within 1.0 second. The problem is that after the animation the UIButton lost his functionality. I can't press it but it is visible. It is a subview of the main view.
Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)nextStep:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Test");


    //Check if the other button is in the view
    if ([theNewPhotoButton isDescendantOfView:self.view]) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{

                             theNewPhotoButton.frame = CGRectMake(-1000, theNewPhotoButton.frame.origin.y, theNewPhotoButton.frame.size.width, theNewPhotoButton.frame.size.height);

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

                             [self.view addSubview:nextButton];
    } else if ([tagView isDescendantOfView:self.view]) {
        if (tagProductArray != nil) {
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 100, 100);
            tagView.frame = CGRectMake(-1000, tagView.frame.origin.y, tagView.frame.size.width, tagView.frame.size.height);

            [self.view addSubview:nextButton];
            [tagView removeFromSuperview];
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you define the frame for `nextButton`?

Comment: Is another view on top of the button? What is the buttons frame?

Comment: Yep, it was hidden. Sorry for that